# Itemize within itemize and reducing indent in beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, itemize

I'm having this problem with `itemize`.

I am preparing a presenation in beamer which requires an itemize within an itemize.

Because of space constraints, I wanted to reduce the identation in the inner itemize through the command `\setlength{\itemindent}{-.2in}`.

However, if I have an item that I create for the inner itemize that requires 2 lines, the second line does not follow the indentation I set for the items in the inner itemize.

For example:

- Point A

  - Point B is too long, would need a new line
    for it

The example above is what I want, but, what I get is that the 2nd line "for it" is shifted to the right, i.e. it's not aligned with Point B from the line above.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the code I have with the screenshot for the output:

```
        \begin{itemize}

        \setlength{\itemindent}{-.2in}
        \item Point A1: 

            \begin{itemize}
            \setlength{\itemindent}{-.2in}
                 \item Point B is so long that it needs two lines 
                 \item 
            \end{itemize}                           

        \item Point A2:

        \item Point A3:         

    \end{itemize}
```

[image]

As you can see above, the "needs two lines" is not aligned with Point B.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example with what you've done, demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Hi Bernard, I generated an example as shown above. I hope it clarifies the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't change the `\itemindent` but the `\leftmargini` (for the first level list) or `\leftmarginii` (second level list).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{0.5cm}
        \begin{itemize}

%        \setlength{\itemindent}{-.2in}
        \item Point A1: 

            \begin{itemize}
%            \setlength{\itemindent}{-.2in}
                 \item Point B is so long that it needs two lines longer longer longer longer longer 
                 \item 
            \end{itemize}                           

        \item Point A2:

        \item Point A3:         

    \end{itemize}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This can also be used globally, i.e., outside of the frame environment.